# Insertar en Mysql no ejecuta

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Cuando quiero insertar información en mi base de datos, este no se ejecuta:

```
$sql_in = "INSERT INTO solicitudes(codsol, nro, fechacrea, rutus, banco, tipocuenta, nrocuenta, actividad, lugar, fechaact, proveedor, rutprov, factura, rex, listado, ordencompra, fechacompro, nrocompro, fechaconta, nroconta, fechateso, nroteso, cheque, transfer, estado, codpres, cospago) VALUES ('$codsol_new','$Nsol_new','NOW()','18128661k',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";

if (isset($_POST['enviar_sol'])) {

    $result_in = $Con_BD->query($sql_in);
```

Ese es el código de la consulta insertar. Llevo un rato con este error, ¿dónde está el problema? ¿qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola, necesitaríamos saber que error te reporta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Como te dice el compañero de arriba, intenta poner el error que te tira mysql

Comment: Primera verificación: ¿Hay un valor por cada columna indicada en el INSERT? Si todos los campos a los que mandas `NULL` adquiriesen ese valor por defecto, podrías omitirlos de la sentencia, al menos en este caso. Y como nota, tu código es vulnerable a la Inyección de Código. Es un agujero de seguridad muy delicado el cual no puedes ignorar.

Comment: Primero, no veo dónde defines las variables que estás **interpolando manualmente en tu query**. Como dijo @A.Cedano esto es mala idea, pero en fin, no es lo que nos convoca. Segundo, no veo que cierres el IF. **Tercero y más importante**, para insertar el `datetime` actual se usa `NOW()` sin comillas. Tú estás insertando un string que dice "NOW()" y probablemente MySQL no te va a aceptar eso en una columna de tipo datetime o timestamp

Comment: @amenadiel pon eso como respuesta para que pueda ser aceptada y sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios

Comment: @SebastianSanchez Por favor, lee [ask] y [answer]. Stack Overflow no funciona como foros online en los que editas la publicación para poner la respuesta; hay una zona específica para respuestas. Voy a editar tu pregunta para quitar el comentario sobre la solución, por favor escríbela como respuesta o espera a que amenadiel (el usuario que la sugirió en un comentario) la publique como respuesta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro como el usuario no respondió más, no tengo cómo saber si eso solucionó el problema.

Comment: @amenadiel el usuario editó la pregunta para poner "solucionado, era el now()". Pero se ha quitado esa edición.

Comment: Bueno, ahí está la respuesta. @AlvaroMontoro, ojalá le sirva a alguien

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia

```
$sql_in = "INSERT INTO solicitudes(codsol, nro, fechacrea, rutus, banco, tipocuenta, nrocuenta, actividad, lugar, fechaact, proveedor, rutprov, factura, rex, listado, ordencompra, fechacompro, nrocompro, fechaconta, nroconta, fechateso, nroteso, cheque, transfer, estado, codpres, cospago) 
           VALUES 
           ('$codsol_new','$Nsol_new','NOW()','18128661k',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";
```

Está insertando el texto `"NOW()"` en un campo de tipo `datetime` (o tal vez `timestamp`). Simplificando, lo que haces es:

```
 $sql_in = "INSERT INTO solicitudes(codsol, nro, fechacrea, rutus) 
            VALUES ('$codsol_new',  '$Nsol_new','NOW()','18128661k')";
```

Ejecutar esa sentencia debiese haber tirado el error:

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column
>   'fechacrea' at row 1

Pero tu pregunta no muestra si acaso estás capturando los errores o excepciones de la BBDD en tu código.

**Lo importante: ocupa la función `NOW` (sin comillas)**

```
 $sql_in = "INSERT INTO solicitudes(codsol, nro, fechacrea, rutus) 
            VALUES ('$codsol_new',  '$Nsol_new', NOW() ,'18128661k')";
```